# Google Cloud Platform - Vanity Nameservers

Tags: google-cloud-dns

I'm in the process of moving my DNS to Google Cloud Platform and wish to set up vanity nameservers.

Is this possible with gloud?

I have two domains currently in my project

abc-net.co.uk (vanity)
abc.co.uk (company domain)

I have set 4 records of

```
ns1.abc-net.co.uk A -> 216.239.32.109 (ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com)
ns2.abc-net.co.uk A -> 216.239.34.109 (ns-cloud-d2.googledomains.com)
ns3.abc-net.co.uk A -> 216.239.36.109 (ns-cloud-d3.googledomains.com)
ns4.abc-net.co.uk A -> 216.239.38.109 (ns-cloud-d4.googledomains.com)
```

I have compiled all records in my project for abc.co.uk but when I run a dig against @ns1.abc-net.co.uk it tells me recursion is not allowed

Can I not set up vanity nameservers?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Instead of A records hardcoding the IPv4 address of ns-cloud-d#.googledomains.com, create 4 CNAME records, ns#.abc-net.co.uk, pointing to the ns-cloud-d#.googledomains.com servers. Then, your NS record would be all four of the ns#.abc-net.co.uk names that you made CNAME records for. I just did this with my domain and it is working great.

This allows the IP addresses of Google's resolver servers to change without breaking your DNS functionality. Additionally, IPv6 clients will resolve over IPv6.

Comment: CNAME records are not permitted in NS records.

Answer (score 5):

### NS Specification

NS records must point to address records (e.g. A and AAAA) and **not to alias records** (e.g. CNAME).

- see [RFC 2181 section 10.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2181#section-10.3)

### Summary

Correctly creating Google Cloud vanity nameservers is possible, but does require the risk of future server down-time if Google changes any nameserver IP addresses associated with your vanity nameservers. If such a risk does not bother you, use the following directions to create them.

### Directions

Note: The following directions were provided at a time when IPv4 A and IPv6 AAAA records ruled the web.

1. Get each nameserver's IPv4 and IPv6 address.

````
``` $ host ns-cloud-x0.googledomains.com ```<br/><br/>
````

2. Create A and AAAA records for each vanity nameserver at your domain's local DNS zone.
3. Register each vanity nameserver's [FQDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name), IPv4, and IPv6 with your domain's registrar (e.g. Enom and GoDaddy).
4. Wait for your registrar to confirm the addition of your vanity nameservers.
5. Wait 24-72 hours to allow the new DNS records time to propagate.
6. Update the NS and SOA records of your domains to point to your vanity servers.

Comment: I'm stuck at step 3. Can you give a more detailed explanation for that, please? I'm using godaddy

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is perfectly doable with Google Domains.

1. In the *Custom resource records* section, create A records and point them to Google DNS servers (`ns1.abc-net.co.uk A -> 216.239.32.109`, etc.), exactly as you did above
2. In the *Registered hosts* section, create glue records (`ns1.abc-net.co.uk`, etc.), pointing them to the same Google servers
3. In the *Nameservers* section, enter your custom name servers (`ns1.abc-net.co.uk`, etc.).
4. Wait for DNS propagation (it will be near instant if you use Google or Cloudflare DNS resolver).

Note that you won't be able to have DNSSEC active.

Hope this helps.