# Use Google Cloud DNS toto Create Vanity Nameservers?

Tags: dns, nameservers, google-cloud-dns

I would like to set up our own name servers for our company - to look more professional, but also to ease future transitions to different servers.  So for example:

ns1.mycompany.com
ns2.mycompany.com

I have a Google Cloud Platform account with access to the Google Cloud DNS API.  My first question is... can I achieve this with Google Cloud DNS?

And if so... how/where do "point" domains to our services such as hosting and mail?

For example, I ask a client to change the name servers for client.com to ns1.mycompany.com and ns2.mycompany.com.  And I have these name servers created in Google Cloud DNS.  How/where do I then set the A or CNAME records to point to our host server and our mail server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need them to point their entire domain to your name servers? why not just tell them to point an A or CNAME record to your records. I would be a little concerned at a company wanting to take control of my entire domain.

Comment: @MichaelB - Many of our clients use our services for all aspects of their domain - web, email, etc.  They are under no obligation to set the name servers, but it's more convenient for them, as we don't need to (for example) update their DNS if our IP addresses or mail servers change over the years.

Comment: @JohnFlanagan, did you find a solution to this? any idea if the [AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/white-label-name-servers.html) approach works in google cloud DNS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216293/google-cloud-platform-vanity-nameservers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Cloud Platform - Vanity Nameservers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216293/google-cloud-platform-vanity-nameservers)